# How to prevent the acidentally mail sending in my app?

Tags: iphone, email

Too many times i receive mails with no content or with just "Sent from my iPhone". Those mails are sent from the "contact" section in my app.

After a little bit, it became boring.

So, is there any way to prevent the accidentally mail sending? I'm tired to see blank emails!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can not send mail through phones mailApp without user pressing the send button you also can't stop it from sending mail. If it really really bothers you you'll have to encode your own SMTP protocol and start sending mail directly from your code. But is it really worth it?

Or you can make user to type the text into a form (textbox) before calling mail-app. If he wrote something you pass it to mail-app and then he must go trough 'send procedure'

Comment: I don't think so. Effectively you're right, but, i mean, there's the Cancel button. Why don't they press it? I'll deal with it!

I'm thinking to implement that feature.

Comment: That's more of a psychological question :) Yes, they can press the cancel button - but your app can't and shouldn't.

Comment: Yes i know, i was just asking myself why! :D Thanks btw!

Answer (score 2):

Don't think one can do much about the empty mails. (Maybe I haven't received so many yet that it troubles me ;) )

On the there hand the benefit of receiving user mail with a contents outweighs the boring empty mails. So I would just put up with the empty mails and maybe create a filter in the email client.

You could use the addresses for a newsletter with info about your app (with an out-out of course)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the idea! But as you all said, i can't do much with that. I'll deal with it, as i wrote!